# Get human-readable PermissionKinds for a particular RoleDefinition using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, .net

At a site collection level, I can look at the permission levels for the collection at `/sites/siteCollectionname/_layouts/15/role.aspx`, and then I can navigate to a particular permission level and see the specific permissions that are granted to that level at `/sites/siteCollectionname/_layouts/15/editrole.aspx?role=Permission%20Name`

**I want retrieve this information programmatically using CSOM**. I can retrieve a site's *RoleDefinitionCollection* and enumerate the permission levels themselves, including their name, description and 'role type kind'. I now want to, for each *RoleDefinition*, enumerate the base permissions (*PermissionKind*?) that are set on it. For example, for a permission level represented in the below screenshot, I want to output "Add Items, Edit Items, Delete Items, View Items".

I am aware that permissions are [implemented using masks](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157058/what-exactly-is-the-webpermmasks-property) and that this involves a high and low integer, but unsure how to fetch these and then transform them into human-readable permissions.

[image]